# Is it possible to have dependent picklist in DocuSgin powerform?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to have dependent picklist on DocuSign powerform just as we have in Salesforce. Is it possible to have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional fields they work very much like dependant picklists.

They can be in the form of a checkbox, a dropdown or specific text

Here is a how-to article: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-conditional-fields